# list Class in C++

Tags: c++, list, class, linked-list

I'm working on a program that is supposed to read the contents of a file into a linked list in order to create a "hypercard stack" (I've listed the specifics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774027/using-the-c-list-standard-library-to-help-in-linked-list-program)).

I know there's a list Class in the C++ standard library, but since I've never worked with the standard library before, I have no idea how to make it work with this particular problem.

Here is the code I've managed to come up with so far through piecing together bits and pieces of online tutorials I've come across.

My .h file:

```
//program6.h
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node(char code, int num, string data);
    Node(Node & node);
    ~Node();

    bool readFile();
    void setNext(Node* next);
    void print();

private:
    char Code;
    int Num;
    string Data;
    Node *Next;
};
```

My Implementation File:

```
//program6.cpp
#include "program6.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

Node::Node() {
    Code = '\0';
    Num = 0;
    Data = "";
    Next = NULL;
}

Node::Node(char code, int num, string data) {
    Code = code;
    Num = num;
    Data = data;
    Next = NULL;
}

Node::Node(Node & node) {
    Code = node.Code;
    Num = node.Num;
    Data = node.Data;
    Next = NULL;
}

Node::~Node() {
}

bool Node::readFile() {
    char code = '\0';
    int num = 0;
    string data = "";

    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("prog6.dat");

    if(!inputFile) {
        cerr << "Open Faiulre" << endl;
        exit(1);
        return false;
    }

    Node *head = NULL;
    while(!inputFile.eof()) {
        inputFile >> code >> num >> data;

        Node *temp = new Node(code, num, data);
        temp->setNext(head);
        head = temp;
    }

    inputFile.close();
    head->print();
    return true;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* next) {
    Next = next;
}

void Node::print() {
    cout << Code << " " << Num << " " << Data;
    if(Next != NULL) 
        Next->print();
}
```

And my main/test file:

```
//program6test.cpp
#include "program6.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Node list;
    if(list.readFile()) 
        cout << "Success" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Failure" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here is teh file I need to read:

```
i 27 Mary had a little lamb
i 15 Today is a good day
i 35 Now is the time!
i 9 This lab is easy and fun
p
d 35
t
i 37 Better Now.
f
p
h
p
d 27
d 15
d 37
d 9
i 44 This should be it!
t
p
```

**Update**
Thanks to the answer below, I was able to get rid of the "undefined reference" errors I was getting initially, however, here is the error I'm getting when I run the program now.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'St9bad_alloc'
  what():  St9bad_alloc
Aborted
```

Also please keep in mind that while I am getting an error that needs to be resolved, that isn't the primary purpose of this question.

I'm sorry if this is really broad, I don't really understand any of this so don't really know how to narrow it down any further. Can anyone help me figure out how to use the list Class to solve this problem, again, the specifics of the program can be found at the link I provided earlier in the post.

Comment: Why are you declaring the `Node` class in the .cpp file when you've already declared it in one of the .h files that you're including?

Comment: Because I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Also, your `Node::Node(char code, int num, string data)` constructor is saving stuff to local variables rather than to object members.

Comment: So how could I fix that?

Comment: By writing to the object members like you do in the other constructors. That is, `Code = ...;` etc, instead of `char Code = ...;` etc.

Comment: Ok I see, I'm editing the post to reflect these changes.

Comment: @Michael, I've made the changes you mentioned, but am still getting the error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to path both files to gcc on the command line.

```
[cs331129@cs ~]$ g++ -o prog6 program6test.cpp program6.cpp
```

Note that you only need to pass `.cpp` files to the compiler, since it finds its way to the header files via the `#include` directives.

Comment: That got rid of the compiler errors, however, now when I run it I get the errors "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'St9bad_alloc'
  what():  St9bad_alloc
Aborted"

Comment: That's a completely different problem.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the variable "data". Try to run the program in a debugger to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Yeah I know, I updated the original question to include a little more information on what I'm actually asking.

Comment: I don't actually have a debugger, our programs are only tested on the Linux system and every time I've used something other than just a plain text editor to write C++ code, it's ended up causing me more trouble because of the fact that the Linux compiler that is used isn't really up to date.

Comment: There are plenty of debuggers available on linux systems. If you *really* can't use one, just put `cout` statement every other line until you find the line that crashes.

Comment: When running the current code (in OP) in Visual Studios, I get the following errors: "1>Prog6.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Node::~Node(void)" (??1Node@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>Prog6.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __thiscall Node::readFile(void)" (?readFile@Node@@QAE_NXZ) referenced in function _wmain
1>Prog6.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Node::Node(void)" (??0Node@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain"